How do I on Dart on one line write "if a given value to a variable is not an integer"?
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  print("What's your cat's age?");
  var age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    
    if (age == 1){
      print("15");  
    }
    if (age == 2){
      print("24");
    }
    if (age == 3){
      print(24 + 4*2);  
    }
    if (age > 3){
      print(24 + 4*(age - 2));
    }
    if (!(age == int)){ // this here should say that "if the variable age is not an integer"
    } else {
      print("Invalid age!");
    }
  
}

I have not learned yet how to express "if a variable does not hold an integer"
Thank you in advance

You would use is or is! for type tests. That said int.parse returns an int or throws an exception for an invalid value, so the age variable will always hold an integer, but you could do int.tryParse instead which returns an int?.

You can simply use try, catch. With int.parse you will try to turn the string into an integer. If this does not work, if for example the input will be "something", you will not be able to transform this into an integer and an error will be thrown. You can simple catch this error and then proceed however you like.
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  print("What's your cat's age?");
  var input = stdin.readLineSync();
  try {
    int age = int.parse(input!);
    if (age == 1) {
      print("15");
    }
    if (age == 2) {
      print("24");
    }
    if (age == 3) {
      print(24 + 4 * 2);
    }
    if (age > 3) {
      print(24 + 4 * (age - 2));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Invalid age!");
  }
}


Could I use "catch (FormatException) {"?
Thank you

@someperson yes you can see since the error that is being thrown is a FormatException. e symbolizes here every possible exception.

It's better to use is operator. And the negation operator (!) to handle the situation.
if (age is! int) {
  // age is not an integer
}


Additional Info:
About Comparison
The comparison (age == int) will not work because age is an integer value while int is a Type.
If you prefer equality operator, you can use:
if (age.runtimeType == int) {
 // Age is int
}

Or the other way around:
if (age.runtimeType != int) {
  // Age is not int
}

The runtimeType property will return the Type of the variable.
About the Exception
The FormatException is being thrown at the line:
var age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

Because, you're trying to parse the input value directly into int. The int.parse throws the FormatException when it fails to parse the input string.
To silently suppress the error you can actually try int.tryParse:
var age = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

// Now the age can be `int` or `null`
// So just do a check to confirm it's int

if (age == null) {
  print("Age is null, please enter a valid age.");
  return;
}

You'll have much more cleaner code with this :)
Hope this helps :)

You should never suggest using the runtimeType property. It is bad advice since it will return the exact type and not check if a type is compatible with another type. Always use the is check when possible.

Thank you everyone so far. I will properly go through all the answers and comments with time.
